# NSMutuableArray sort problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

NSMutableArray *labels;
and it is properly populated.

```
    NSSortDescriptor* sortOrder = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"self" ascending: NO];
labels = [labels sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject: sortOrder]];
```

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.

Even if I change NSArray to NSMutuableArray in the last line, I still get the error.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using "self" as the sort key?

Comment: To be honest with you, I just copied that code and I am trying to understand this whole sort mechanism.

Comment: I understand it now.  Self was refering to the label I want to sort.  But should have been using self.text.

Answer (score 3):

dont assign the same array to it.if it is nsarray which is immutable.

so do like this

put ur

```
   labels as NSMutableArray


NSMutableArray *resultArray;

NSSortDescriptor* sortOrder = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"self" ascending: NO];


resultArray = [[labels sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortOrder]] mutableCopy];    

self.labels=resultArray;//updated code

NSLog(@"resultArray : %@ \n\n",resultArray);
```

Comment: Why can't you assign to the original array?

Comment: once u created with NSArray with objects then it will never change it objects even u cannot replace.it is immutable.my best idea is use NSMutable array.

Comment: Thanks but my labels is NSMutable.  The question is why do u have to have resultArray = [[labels sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortOrder]] mutableCopy]; instead of labels = [[labels sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortOrder]] mutableCopy];

Comment: [labels sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortOrder]] this line will produce NSArray even ur labels array is an NSMutableArray.so while assing to ur labels .it will be error.so that "mutablecopy" method will change NSArray to NSMutableArray.that's it

Comment: Thanks.  I understand this part.  But my question is why after applying the method "mutablecopy" , it is necessary to assign it to a new array instead of the original labels.

Comment: u can assign it.because ur labels is now immutable by NSMutableArray.

Comment: i expect from u more questions

Comment: Changed to: labels1 = [[labels sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors] mutableCopy]; and still get "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Comment: if u synthesize the labels array then see my above updated code

Comment: I did everything as you said and I am still getting: "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Comment: NSMutableArray *resultArray;
    NSSortDescriptor* sortOrder = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"self" ascending: NO];
    resultArray = [[labels sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortOrder]] mutableCopy];

Comment: I can only enter 600 chars here.  How can I post the whole code(about 6000 chars)

Comment: I understand it now.  Self was refering to the label I want to sort.  But should have been using self.text.

Comment: edit ur question and copy from xcode then paste with formatting

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray * descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: sortOrder, nil];
labels = [labels sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
```

This should do the trick for you.

Comment: Changed the second statement to labels = [[labels sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors] mutableCopy]; to get rid of incompatible type.  Now I get "unrecognized selector sent to instance" when labels has more than one element.

Comment: Changed to: labels1 = [[labels sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors] mutableCopy]; and still get    "unrecognized selector sent to instance"